# not okForStorage Error in MongoDB,Node.Js(mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am using Node.js and MongoDB with mongoose.
When I execute code below,The first code of updating is working properly. But I get an error 'not okForStorage' at second updating query which is inserting 'bar'.

It's for loop and inserting data over and over but the error occurs at the first inserting so I don't think this is payload issue nor any other hardware problem.

```
analyze('SomeText',function(err,data){
if(err) throw err;
    for(var i=0; i < data.foo.length;i++){
        if(!data.foo[i]){
            continue;
        }
        var condtion = { foo: data.foo[i]};
        var update = {
            $inc :{totalcounter : 1},
            counter : {
                date : dateformat(new Date(), "yyyymmdd"),
                $inc :{counter : 1}
            }
        };
        db.foodb.update(condtion,update,{upsert : true},function(err, numberAffected, raw){
            if(err) throw err;
            //Data added successfully
        });
        for(var g=0;g < data.bar[i].length;g++){
            update = {
                bar : { 
                    foo : data.bar[i][g],
                    $inc : { totalcounter : 1},
                    counter : {
                        date : dateformat(new Date(), "yyyymmdd"),
                        $inc :{counter : 1}
                    }
                }
            };
            db.foodb.update(condtion,update,{upsert : true},function(err, numberAffected, raw){
                if(err) throw err;
                //getting error here 'MongoError: not okForStorage'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Let's say reserved data is something like

```
data.foo = ['10','20','30'];
data.bar = [[11,12,13],[21,22,23],[31,32,33]];
```

and How I would like to insert the data to the Database is

```
{ 
    foo : 10,
    totalcounter : 1,
    counter :{ date : 20131231,counter : 1},
    bar : {[ foo : 11,totalcounter : 1,counter : {date : 20131231,counter : 1}],
    [foo : 12,totalcounter : 1,counter : {date : 20131231,counter : 1}],
    [foo : 13,totalcounter : 1,counter : {date : 20131231,counter : 1}]
    }
}
```

In Addition,even though I assign time explicitly such as '20131231'. it would be ignored and the default time in ISODate type(1970-01-01T05:35:40.109Z) would be saved instead.
I understand that I need to follow IOSDate format type to store Date.
But I don't want that to contain hours nor min/sec for some reason.
other than setting 'date' as Number object,is there any efficient way to do that?

Thank you for all your assistance.

Comment: What I've found so far is the way using '$inc' is wrong.
It seems I need to put them together But "$inc : { totalcounter : 1,counter.counter : 1}" give me an syntax error. this might be a very newbie quetion though,Could anyone suggest the proper way to write it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first code of updating is working properly. But I get an error 'not okForStorage' at second updating query which is inserting 'bar'.

Based on the code you pasted, I'm not sure how the first update is executing successfully. In both cases, you're mixing update operators and field replacements in the same update object (the second parameter to `update()`). This is discussed in the [`db.collection.update()` documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-parameter), and it applies to drivers as well.

In your first update, you mean to set the `counter.date` field and increment two other fields, so your update object should be:

```
{
  $inc: { totalcounter : 1, "counter.counter": 1 },
  $set: { date : dateformat(new Date(), "yyyymmdd") }
}
```

Regarding your example document, you wrote:

> How I would like to insert the data to the Database is:
>
> ```
> { 
>     foo : 10,
>     totalcounter : 1,
>     counter :{ date : 20131231,counter : 1},
>     bar : {[ foo : 11,totalcounter : 1,counter : {date : 20131231,counter : 1}],
>     [foo : 12,totalcounter : 1,counter : {date : 20131231,counter : 1}],
>     [foo : 13,totalcounter : 1,counter : {date : 20131231,counter : 1}]
>     }
> }
> ```

I assume there is some typo in your example value for `bar`. Should that be an array of objects? If so, you should probably use one of the [array update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/#array), such as `$push`, if you mean to append a new object to the array. If instead you mean to update existing array elements using the normal modifiers (e.g. `$inc`, `$set`), you can refer to the fields to update with dot-syntax, such as `bar.0.counter` for the `counter` field within the first object in the `bar` array.

> In Addition, even though I assign time explicitly such as '20131231'. It would be ignored and the default time in ISODate ("1970-01-01T05:35:40.109Z") would be saved instead. I understand that I need to follow IOSDate format type to store Date. But I don't want that to contain hours nor min/sec for some reason. Other than setting 'date' as Number object, is there any efficient way to do that?

I assume your Mongoose schema maps the `date` field, and the string `'20131231'` is not a valid constructor argument and an empty ISODate is being created as a result. The BSON date type stores milliseconds since the epoch as a 64-bit integer. If you'd like to ignore hours and smaller measures of time, you can simply create a timestamp with zero for all of those measures.

If you are adamant about storing "YYYYMMDD" strings for the `date` field, you'll just need to change your mapping in Mongoose so the field is a basic string.